# Kafka producer behavior

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying latest kafka version 1.1.0.
I have point which bothering me about producer behavior.

Below is a small piece of code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 3);
props.put("max.in.flight.requests.per.connection", 1);

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", 
   Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)), new CallBack());
```

assumptions

1. each message is sent to the same partition of a topic.
2. Size of each message is large enough that, it is submitted to the broker (not held in the buffer)

Now when the index is 0 and send method fails but for subsequent send call didn't fail, then, in that case, will the message's reach to broker in out of sequence. That is index 0 message will not be the first to reach to broker even if a retry code is added.

Will it be the same behavior if I add below configuration property
    enable.idempotence=true

Is there any elegant approach to handle this situation? that is to maintain the order of messages

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) might be what you are looking for

Comment: How many partitions do you have?